# fire event written in child view in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I am using backbone js.
suppose i have a child view called 'childView' and a parent view called 'parentView'.

```
parentView = Backbone.View.extend({
  render: function () {
    new childView().render();
  }
})

childView = Backbone.View.extend({
  render: function () {

  },
  events: {
    'click .abc' : 'fireEvent'
  }
})
```

I need to call click event written in childView in a parentView.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to use `Backbone.View`'s instance. `Backbone.View` is mixed with `Backbone.Events` which give you possibility to use it as event aggregator.

Example for your case:

```
childView = Backbone.View.extend({
  render: function () {

  },
  events: {
    'click .abc' : 'fireEvent'
  }, 
  fireEvent: function (e) {
      this.trigger('child:event:fired', e);
  }
});
```

And in parent view:

```
parentView = Backbone.View.extend({
  render: function () {
    this.childView = new childView();
    this.childView.on('child:event:fired', this.onChildEvent, this);
    childView .render();
  }, 
  onChildEvent: function (e) {
        console.log("child view event");
  },
  closeThisView: function () {
    this.childView.off('child:event:fired', this.onChildEvent, this);
  }
})
```

This way you can subscribe to childView events, but you need to manually manage unbinding from all subscriptions.

---

Another solution for the same issue can be found by declaring global event aggregator for both views.

```
var vent = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
```

And in your views just trigger needed events with `vent.trigger` and subscribe/unsubscribe with `vent.(on/off)` methods.