# How to get active Backbone view correctly?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I have Backbone view that has sub-views and each of the could stay "active" (just `click` or `contextmenu`). And I need to get view reference to that active sub-view from parent view. What is the correct way to do it?

My view hierarchy looks like the following:

```
var OuterView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.children = {};
        this.child = new Backbone.View();
        this.children[this.child.cid] = this.child;
    },

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html('<div data-view-cid="' + this.child.cid + '"></div>');
        _.each(this.children, function(view, cid) {
            this.$('[data-view-cid="' + cid + '"]').replaceWith(view.el);
        }, this);
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you provide some source code for this issue?

Comment: There is a lot of ways to do that and your way also can be accepted.

Comment: I guess the main question is - How to delegate event of the child view to the parent view?

Comment: @Vahan Vardanyan could you provide some of approaches please?

Comment: Sure. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27314230/fire-event-written-in-child-view-in-backbone-js/27316688#27316688) my answer to the similiar question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The approach I prefer is not to have active and inactive views, but to only render the view that is active, and to remove them when not needed.

In other words, the easiest way to handle state is to make things stateless.

Comment: I little bit disagree with you. Let's imagine google docs toolbar. When user adds new table row (for example) by using toolbar button and document itself could have multiple tables, how could we know which table is current?

Comment: Sure, there are always places where you have to keep the notion of active. I guess my point is it makes life much easier when we avoid it as much as possible

Comment: Ok, but I have web application like Google Docs and I'm looking for solution how to implement keeping of active object. Could you point me to the right direction?

Comment: Typically what I do is keep a "state" object, this extends a model, and basically holds the current UI state. For instance: pagination data, Is the page in edit mode or read mode, etc, so I can see how you could store a ref to the active table in the state object

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution would be to delegate the parent view to listen to 'click div' and in the callback get the child view by `$(event.currentTarget).closest('[data-view-cid]')`

The child view should not be aware of the parent view to avoid creating zombies, otherwise you might have to clean up the references.